# Pull the Wifi history from a iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, wifi

I'm using an iPhone 3GS, and for reasons relating to an art project I was wondering if I can pull a list of known wifi's, without specifically going to where the wifi is transmitting of course. Is there a safe way to do this? I assume this is on the SQLite db? Be interested what is know on the topic, or where to being researching anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Check out SpyPhone. It exemplifies similar information which you can pull from an iPhone.

https://github.com/nst/spyphone/

You can easily just download it and run it on your device if you don't need to do it programmatically yourself. If you do, you can easily rip out the code.

Cheers!